# Open a website in an iframe instead of a new window

Tags: javascript, html

Once I click on a button, it should open a website in an `iframe`, and the  modal should not have a URL since it is showing in new window. The modal should be in the center of the window. As I know its easy with Bootstrap but I wanted to do this in pure JavaScript.

**HTML Code**

```
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="executeOnClick()" id="w3schools">
    Open Website
</button>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function executeOnClick(){
        var win = open('http://www.w3schools.com/', 'example', 'width=600,height=450')
        win.focus();
        win.onload = function() {
            var div = win.document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = 'Welcome into the future!';
            div.style.fontSize = '30px';
            win.document.body.insertBefore( div, win.document.body.firstChild )
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the simple modal idea from [here](https://raventools.com/blog/create-a-modal-dialog-using-css-and-javascript/) a long time ago, but it's so simple, and it still works flawlessly. I added the button for demonstration purposes, but you'll probably need to change it to compliment whatever UI you got going there.

Let me know if this is what you want because your explanation is worded a little awkward (not referring to your grammar, rather that it is difficult to describe certain things like this verbally or by text.)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>34608282</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font: 400 16px/1.45"Verdana";
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0 none hlsa(0%, 0, 0, 0);
      outline: 0 none hlsa(0%, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    body {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #111;
      color: #EEE;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    #overlay {
      display: none;
      position: relative;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 101vw;
      height: 101vh;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 1111;
    }
    #overlay section {
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 640px;
      height: 360px;
      margin: 10px auto;
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid yellow;
      border-radius: 8px;
      padding: 15px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    #test {
      position: absolute;
      top: 25%;
      left: 25%;
      width: 128px;
      height: 48px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      border: 1px outset yellow;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      font-variant: small-caps;
      color: yellow;
      background: #222;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="test">Test Modal</button>
  <aside id="overlay">
    <section>
      <iframe id="iFrame" name="iFrame" src="http://example.com/" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </section>
  </aside>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', modal, false);

    function modal() {
      var ov = document.getElementById("overlay");
      ov.style.display = (ov.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For this, create and `iframe` and put it inside a `div` with its `display` set to `none`. Now after opening the modal window, you can write the `innerHTML` of this `div` i.e. the `iframe` using `document.write`. 
Try this:

```js
function executeOnClick(){
  document.getElementById('ifram1').src = 'http://www.w3schools.com';
  var divContents = document.getElementById('modal').innerHTML;
  alert(divContents);
  var modalWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=500,width=500');
  modalWindow.document.write('<html>');
  modalWindow.document.write('<body>');
  modalWindow.document.write(divContents);
  modalWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
  modalWindow.document.close();
  
  }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="executeOnClick()" id="w3schools">
    Open Website
</button>
<br/>
<div id="modal" style='display:none;'>
<iframe name="theFrame" id="ifram1"></iframe>
  </div>
```

NOTE: This is not working in the code snippet, and also in JSFiddle (it says: document.write is disallowed in JSFiddle environment and might break your fiddle). However, I have tested this in my local machine and it is working as expected. Please check. Hope this helps.

Here is a screenshot from my local machine:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try It

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p><a href="http://www.runway73.com" target="iframe_a">Click For New Website</a></p>
<iframe width="300px" height="300px" src="http://facebook.com/" name="iframe_a"></iframe>


</body>
</html>
```